# Paracompactness and Filters

Tags: general-topology, reference-request, filters

If one use ultrafilters to describe a compact space, one gets Tychonoff Theorem as a trivial result. So, im just asking if there is such a "useful" equivalence, but concerning paracompact spaces ( e.g. Smirnov-Theorem in the language of filters, since it has Hausdorff condition - any filters converges at most to one point - and the paracompactness condition - "some useful description of those spaces with filter")

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

J.D. Wine, [*Paracompactifications using filter bases*](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.pjm/1102945290), Pacific J. Math. Volume 49, Number 1 (1973), 285-304, gives a number of characterizations of paracompactness in terms of $z$-filters and various kinds of filter bases. You’ll have to make your own judgement of their usefulness!